# Is there a way to directly take the content of a user's message in Discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm making a Discord Bot and I need to it automatically take an input from the sender that typed 'o-convo' without needing a prefix. The bot will then respond to the message and will be ready to wait for questions again. Is there a way to directly take the content of a user's message? I have made an attempt at this, but the bot does not respond. There are no errors in the console. If anyone could provide details, that would be greatly appreciated!

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('o-convo'):
          channel = message.channel
          BotUser = message.author
          await channel.send("Conversation locked with " + str(BotUser) + ". Type o-quit to exit.")
          while True:
            async def on_message(message):
              if message.author == BotUser:
                convo_message = message.content()
                response = bot.get_response(convo_message)
                await message.channel.send(response)
              elif message.content.lower().startswith('o-quit'):
                return
              else:
                return
            break
```

Comment: Probably because you have a `break` at the end of your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an `async def on_message` inside of your loop will not work, as there is nothing telling the library to call it.

Instead, the library provides a way to do this via [Bot.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Which has an example provided on how to wait for a particular message, which is much like your current `if message.author == BotUser:` line.

So instead of creating an async def you would do something similar to:

```py
    if message.content.lower().startswith('o-convo'):
        channel = message.channel
        BotUser = message.author
        await channel.send("Conversation locked with " + str(BotUser) + ". Type o-quit to exit.")
        while True:
            def check(m):
                return m.author == BotUser or m.content.lower().startswith('o-quit')
            response = await bot.wait_for("message",check=check)
            if response.content.startswith("o-quit"):
                break
            else:
                await message.channel.send(response.content)
```

Comment: Also a good hint for him would probably be that it's `message.content` what he was searching for and he also used `message.content()` which would be to call the function which doesn't exists because it's a variable

Comment: Alright so sorry for the late reply, the code does indeed listen for when a message is sent and if o-quit is returned. However, I don’t know how to get value/text of the message that was sent as a response to the prompt.

Comment: Thats what `response.content` does

Comment: Ah I see, I got it to work now, I just had to change the code a little. Thank you so much!